# code stopped working after wordpress update 4.8.2

Tags: php, wordpress

I tried with the code provided but it stil doesn't work...
and it started giving problems only after updating to wordpress 4.8.2
I copy also the code with the following parte where I close the foreach and the if ...
With Wordpress 4.7.6 works perfectly...
Any Idea?
Thanks a lot for the help!

```
  <?php
        $cat_array = array();
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'posts_per_page' => 9,
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
        );
        $my_query = null;
        $my_query = new WP_Query($args);

        if ($my_query->have_posts())
        {
            while ($my_query->have_posts()):
                $my_query->the_post();
                $cat_args = array(
                    'orderby' => 'none'
                );

                $cats = wp_get_post_terms($my_query->post->ID, 'category', $cat_args);
                foreach($cats as $cat)
                {
                    $cat_array[$cat->term_id] = $cat->term_id;
                }

            endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();
        }

        if ($cat_array)
        {
            foreach($cat_array as $cat)
            {
                $category = get_term_by('ID', $cat, 'category');
                $slug = get_term_link($category, 'category');
                $id = $category->term_id;
                $valore = "category_" . $id;
                $colore = get_field('colore_categoria', $valore);
                $immagine = get_field('immagine_ispirazione', $valore);
                $testo_box = get_field('testo_box', $valore);


        ?>

        <div class="colonna clearfix">
            <a href="<?php echo $slug;?>">
                <div class="box">
                    <img src="<?php echo $immagine?>" alt="italia">
                    <div class="overlay">
                    <p><?php echo $testo_box;?></p>
                </div>
                <div class="titolobox"  style="background-color:<?php echo $colore;?>">
                    <h2><?php echo $category->name;?></h2>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>

        </div>

    <?php
    }


}

wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `'ignore_sticky_posts'` instead of `'caller_get_posts'`.
You can refer to [this page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to update your query

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your requirement but I think you didn't close the the foreach loop and if condition, and also I think that you need advance custom field value of category  assigned to the post for that you should use

```
wp_get_post_categories( int $post_id, array $args = array() )
```

in your while loop. hope this help.

and you should use "ignore_sticky_posts"  rather than "caller_get_posts"

Answer (score 0):

use bellow code.

```
<?php
$cat_array = array();
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 9,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
);
$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($my_query->have_posts())
{
    while ($my_query->have_posts()):
        $my_query->the_post();
        $cat_args = array(
            'orderby' => 'none'
        );
        $cats = wp_get_post_terms($my_query->post->ID, 'category', $cat_args);
        foreach($cats as $cat)
        {
            $cat_array[$cat->term_id] = $cat->term_id;
        }

    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
}

if ($cat_array)
{
    foreach($cat_array as $cat)
    {
        $category = get_term_by('ID', $cat, 'category');
        $slug = get_term_link($category, 'category');
        $id = $category->term_id;
        $valore = "category_" . $id;
        $colore = get_field('colore_categoria', $valore);
        $immagine = get_field('immagine_ispirazione', $valore);
        $testo_box = get_field('testo_box', $valore);
    }
}

?>
```

enjoy